# Vuex and Firebase store state errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuex

I have the following setup in my vuex store: My users log in with Firebase authentication. Upon login, `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is called and `user` is set to `state.user` but also saved in the Firebase database. The moment when I add the last part of my code (`database.ref...`) my console explodes with errors. The errors, however, are not related to Firebase but to Vuex.

Errors are the following (x80):

> [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "function () { return this._data.$$state }":
>
> Error: [vuex] Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.

My code still works, but during development, I don't want to see 80 errors as the user logs in. How can I get rid of these errors?

```
// actions
const actions = {
  startListeningToAuth ({ commit }) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      commit(types.SET_USER, { user })
    })
  }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  [types.SET_USER] (state, { user }) {
    state.user = user

    if (user) {
      database.ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email,
        photo_url: user.photoURL
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use toJSON() method to the firebase.User interface

```
commit(types.SET_USER, { user.toJSON() })
```

This will allow to add user data to your store without warnings but i guess that you can lose the realtime user state from firebase.

See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#toJSON

Answer (score 0):

Mutations should only contain code that directly affects the vuex `state`.

You are getting the errors because `database.ref()` is most likely modifying the `user` object in some way. In your mutation, `state.user = user` makes it so that your `state.user` object is referencing the same object as your `user` variable. So, if `user` changes outside of the mutation, the state will also change, and Vue will yell at you.

You should move your `database.ref()` call to the related action method and then commit the mutation. Since `database.ref()` is async, you need to wait for that method to finish before committing the mutation:

```
// actions
const actions = {
  startListeningToAuth ({ commit }) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        database.ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
          name: user.displayName,
          email: user.email,
          photo_url: user.photoURL
        }).then(() => {
          commit(types.SET_USER, { user })
        })
      }
    })
  }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
  [types.SET_USER] (state, { user }) {
    state.user = user
  }
}
```

Comment: is `database.ref` an async call?

Comment: Yes it is async

Comment: @user3178862 ok you'll need to wait for the call to finish then. See my updated answer

Comment: It clearly helped me with the issue, but still not completely removed it. Instead of having the error calls like 80 times now they only appear once.

Comment: Is `onAuthStateChanged` async as well? If so, try `.then(() => { commit(...` after onAuthStateChanged().

Comment: Then there must be somewhere else in your code where the state is being affected

Answer (score 0):

Did you want set user data after register? 
this is my code to do this

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((user) => {
                    //init user
                    userRef.child(user.uid).set({
                        email: email,
                        //Other data 
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    state.isRegenter code hereister = false;
                    console.log(error);
});
```